# How do I format a date in ruby to include "rd" as in "3rd"

Tags: ruby, strftime

I want to format a date object so that I can display strings such as "3rd July" or "1st October". I can't find an option in Date.strftime to generate the "rd" and "st". Any one know how to do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm going to echo everyone else, but I'll just encourage you to download the `activesupport` gem, so you can just use it as a library.  You don't need all of Rails to use [`ordinalize`](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/Inflector.html).

```
% gem install activesupport
...
% irb 
irb> require 'rubygems'
#=>  true
irb> require 'activesupport'
#=>  true
irb> 3.ordinalize
#=>  "3rd"
```

Comment: Good point.  You can also get this functionality from the facets (http://facets.rubyforge.org) library - require 'facets' or, for just this method, require 'facets/integer/ordinal'

Comment: How do we extract just the ordinalization? I want to do ``3<span>th</span>``

Comment: Volte: `3.ordinalize.sub(/\w+/, '<span>\0</span>')`

Comment: There's a much easier way to get what you want without manipulating the day integer by hand: `date.to_s(:long_ordinal)`. See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-i-to_formatted_s

Answer (score 41):

Unless you're using *Rails*, add this *ordinalize* method (code shamelessly
lifted from the Rails source) to the *Fixnum* class

```
class Fixnum
  def ordinalize
    if (11..13).include?(self % 100)
      "#{self}th"
    else
      case self % 10
        when 1; "#{self}st"
        when 2; "#{self}nd"
        when 3; "#{self}rd"
        else    "#{self}th"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then format your date like this:

```
> now = Time.now
> puts now.strftime("#{now.day.ordinalize} of %B, %Y")
=> 4th of July, 2009
```

Comment: Note that this answer is a bit outdated. [Here's how it looks like now](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3f96b6973b82ad17e443dd1d21be05996fb6fbf0/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb#L312-L347) and [here's the extension to the `Integer` class](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/08754f12e65a9ec79633a605e986d0f1ffa4b251/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/integer/inflections.rb).

Answer (score 31):

```
created_at.strftime("#{created_at.day.ordinalize} of %m, %y")
```

Will produce "4th of July, 2009"

Comment: I had to add a # in front of the { but this worked a treat Thanks!

Comment: how would you ordinalize the string variables? I need to turn %m for example.

Comment: This is nice when you need to use the atypical "4th of July" format but there's no need to ordinalize by hand if you're using the conventional "July 4th, 2009": `created_at.to_date.to_s(:long_ordinal)`.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think Ruby has it, but if you have Rails, try this:-

```
puts 3.ordinalize #=> "3rd"
```

Comment: It's also available in Facets.

Answer (score 1):

Seems I'm revisiting this topic for a third time, so I've updated my gist with some extra comments / usage.

https://gist.github.com/alterisian/4154152

Cheers,
Ian.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it makes it that much (any?) faster than switch-case, but I made a constant with the endings:

```
DAY_ENDINGS = ["th", "st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "st"]
```

Then just used it like:

```
DAY_ENDINGS[date.mday]
```

As I wanted the ending inside a

```
<span>th</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

require 'activesupport'
1.ordinal => 'st' 
1.ordinalize => '1st'

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'time'
```

```
H = Hash.new do |_,k|
  k +
  case k
  when '1', '21', '31'
    'st'
  when '2', '22'
    'nd'
  when '3', '23'
    'rd'
  else
    'th'
  end
end
```

```
def fmt_it(time)
  time.strftime("%A %-d, %-l:%M%P").sub(/\d+(?=,)/, H) 
end
```

```
fmt_it(Time.new)
  #=> "Wednesday 9th, 1:36pm"
```

```
fmt_it(Time.new + 3*24*60*60)
  #=> "Saturday 12th, 3:15pm"
```

I have used the form of [String#sub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-sub) (one could use `sub!`) that takes a hash (`H`) as its second argument.

The regular expression used by `sub` reads "match one or more digits followed by a comma". `(?=,)` is a *positive lookahead*.

I created the (empty) hash `H` using the form of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes a block. This simply means that if `H` does not have a key `k`, `H[k]` returns the value computed by the block. In this case the hash is empty so the block always returns the value of interest. The block takes two arguments, the hash (here `H`) and the key being evaluated. I've represented the former with an underscore, signalling that it is not used by the block). Some examples:

```
H['1']  #=>  "1st" 
H['2']  #=>  "2nd" 
H['3']  #=>  "3rd" 
H['4']  #=>  "4th" 
H['9']  #=>  "9th" 
H['10'] #=> "10th" 
H['11'] #=> "11th" 
H['12'] #=> "12th" 
H['13'] #=> "13th" 
H['14'] #=> "14th" 
H['22'] #=> "22nd" 
H['24'] #=> "24th" 
H['31'] #=> "31st"
```

See [Time#strftime](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Time:strftime) for formatting directives.