# Ruby formatting for ordinals: '1' as '1st', '2' as '2nd' etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string-formatting

Is anything baked into ruby or rails to handle formatting for ordinals:  '1' as '1st', '2' as '2nd', etc.?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I format a date in ruby to include "rd" as in "3rd"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081926/how-do-i-format-a-date-in-ruby-to-include-rd-as-in-3rd)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165170/in-ruby-on-rails-how-do-i-format-a-date-with-the-th-suffix-as-in-sun-oct-5t

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for ordinalize:

> The Ruby on Rails framework is chock full of interesting little nuggets. Ordinalize is a number extension that returns the corresponding ordinal number as a string. For instance, 1.ordinalize returns “1st” and 22.ordinalize return “22nd”.
>
> Example:
>
> place = 3
> puts "You are currently in #{place.ordinalize} place."
>
> Result:
>
> You are currently in 3rd place.