# Date Format In RUBY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Here, In RUBY I need a format of Like this

> "February 1st 2011 11.00"

. I tried this one

```
"Time.now.utc.strftime("%B %d %Y %R")"
```

But I need to format numerals with suffixes st, nd, rd, th etc. Please suggest something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you specifically want "February 1st 2011 11.00" you would need to add your own DATE_FORMATS and call that.

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:custom_ordinal] = lambda { |time| time.strftime("%B #{ActiveSupport::Inflector.ordinalize(time.day)} %Y %H.%M") }

puts Time.now.to_s(:custom_ordinal)
# February 28th 2011 02.12
```

If all you want is an ordinal date and "February 28th, 2011 02:12" works, then call Time.now.to_s(:long_ordinal)

Answer (score 1):

Install gem `activesupport`, and use method `ordinalize`:

[How do I format a date in ruby to include "rd" as in "3rd"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081926/how-do-i-format-a-date-in-ruby-to-include-rd-as-in-3rd)