# How do I display a date with the th/st/nd appended appropriately after the number with Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I've looked all around, but couldn't find anything on this. I know I can format a date as say, "January 12, 2013" but how would I add the "th", so it would be "January 12th, 2013"? It would also need to figure out if it should use "nd" or "st" instead.

Comment: See also: [Ordinalize date formatting in Liquid/Jekyll (e.g. 1st, 3rd and 4th)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18892909/102401).

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with Liquid alone, but you can write a Liquid tag to show the date in the desired format. :)

[You should take a look at the #ordinalize method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081926/how-do-i-format-a-date-in-ruby-to-include-rd-as-in-3rd) from ActiveSupport to create your own (or `require` the library). Wrap it [around a Liquid Tag](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#tags) and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this Liquid snippet that produces "ordinalized" dates without requiring plug-ins.

```
{% assign d = page.date | date: "%d" | plus:'0' %}
{{ page.date | date: "%B" }} 
{% case d %}
  {% when 1 or 21 or 31 %}{{ d }}st
  {% when 2 or 22 %}{{ d }}nd
  {% when 3 or 23 %}{{ d }}rd
  {% else %}{{ d }}th
  {% endcase %}, 
{{ page.date | date: "%Y" }}
```

Not only does the code add the "st", "nd", etc... strings, it also removes leading zeros from the first nine days of each month. The dates produces look like this:

```
July 4th, 2013
```

If you're interested in other date formatting options, I also put together this [full set of Jekyll Liquid date formatting examples](http://alanwsmith.com/jekyll-liquid-date-formatting-examples). It contains snippets for several useful options like: "2013-09-23", "September 23, 2013" and "Sept. 23rd, 2013".

---

*Note: That code is split to multiple lines to make it readable in this answer. You'll probably want to move it to a single line to avoid whitespace issues in production. I don't know how version specific any of what I used is, but the code works on a Mac running OS X 10.8.5 with: Ruby 2.0.0p247 - Jekyll 1.2.1 - liquid 2.5.2.*