# Ordinalize date formatting in Liquid/Jekyll (e.g. "1st", "3rd" and "4th")

Tags: jekyll, liquid

Is it possible to add day of the month suffixes to a date format in Liquid or Jekyll? For example: January 23rd or May 18th.

I've referred to the [Shopify wiki](http://wiki.shopify.com/Date), but I'm shocked to see that there's no formatting there for it. Surely something that simple should be? :/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Liquid Template Engine that [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) uses doesn't offer the ability to ordinalize (e.g. turn "1" into "1st" and "3" into "3rd") out of the box. However, it is possible to use filters and tags to provide that functionality. The snippet below produces the day of month number with an ordanilized string appended. It also removes the leading zero for the first nine days of the month.

```
{% assign d = page.date | date: "%-d" %}
{% case d %}
  {% when "1" or "21" or "31" %}{{ d }}st
  {% when "2" or "22" %}{{ d }}nd
  {% when "3" or "23" %}{{ d }}rd
  {% else %}{{ d }}th
{% endcase %}
```

For a full date with month, day and year, use this:

```
{% assign d = page.date | date: "%-d" %}
{{ page.date | date: "%B" }} 
{% case d %}{% when "1" or "21" or "31" %}{{ d }}st{% when "2" or "22" %}{{ d }}nd{% when "3" or "23" %}{{ d }}rd{% else %}{{ d }}th{% endcase %}, 
{{ page.date | date: "%Y" }}
```

which produces output like:

```
September 21st, 2013
```

*Note: The code is split onto multiple lines to make it easier to read. It will render fine in HTML but will have extra whitespace in the source code. If that bothers you, simply move everything to one line.*

If you are interested in other date formatting options, I create this reference: [Jekyll (and GitHub Pages) Liquid Date Formatting Examples](http://alanwsmith.com/jekyll-liquid-date-formatting-examples)

Comment: Don't use `plus: '0'`. Use: `{{ page.date | date: "%-m-%d-%Y" }}`. Notice the hyphen between `%` and m: `%-m`.

Comment: @DamianNowak - I've updated the `%-d` call used in the snippet. Thanks for the pointer to the more elegant way to strip leading zeros.