# How do I add an unlimited amount of people in my ruby program

Tags: ruby

I wrote a program that would see if you are on a party list. It works fine, but I wan't to add something so you can choose how many people are in your party compared to the default of five in this one. Thanks, any help would be appreciated. I just started so sorry if I don't understand.

```
puts "Create a party"
puts "Who is the first person: "
first_person = gets.chomp.upcase()
puts "Who is the second person: "
second_person = gets.chomp.upcase()
puts "Who is the third person: "
third_person = gets.chomp.upcase()
puts "Who is the fourth person: "
fourth_person = gets.chomp.upcase()
puts "Who is the fifth person: "
fifth_person = gets.chomp.upcase()

friends_list = Array[first_person, second_person, third_person, fourth_person, fifth_person]

puts "What is your name?"
your_name = gets.chomp.upcase()

if friends_list.include? your_name
  puts "Congrats, you were invited"
else
  puts "Sorry, you weren't invited. Please check with the host of the party for more details"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example grouping instructions in methods so you can reuse some (see `get_name`), to be [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Also, it uses a hash to store person details into the array.

The program keeps running in `loop to` until it breaks by user input.

```
def run
  people = []
  loop do
    show_options
    answer = gets.chomp.downcase.to_sym
    case answer
    when :a
      add_person_to people
    when :l
      list people
    when :f
      find_in people
    else
      break
    end
  end
end

def show_options
  puts "-"*50
  puts "A: add person"
  puts "L: list people"
  puts "F: find person"
  puts "any other key: exit"
end

def get_name
  puts "Name?"
  name = gets.chomp.capitalize
  puts "Nickname?"
  nickname = gets.chomp.capitalize
  {name: name, nickname: nickname}
end

def add_person_to people
  puts "Adding person nr. #{people.size + 1}"
  people << get_name # check if already present?
end

def list people
  puts "-"*50
  people.each { |person| puts "Name: #{person[:name]} - Nickname: #{person[:nickname]}" }
  puts "Total people: #{people.size}"
end

def find_in people
  puts people.include? get_name # or improve
end

run # this calls the run method
```

Comment: Thanks mate, Helped a lot. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

That's great you've started to learn Ruby!

You can use loop. Make an array first and `push` the names into it.

```
puts "Create a party"
puts "Enter blank if you are done"

friends_list = []  # new array
count = 1
loop do
  print count.to_s + "th person's name: "
  name = gets.chomp.upcase
  break if name.empty?
  friends_list.push(name)  # add person to list
  count += 1
end

puts "What is your name?"
your_name = gets.chomp.upcase()

if friends_list.include? your_name
  puts "Congrats, you were invited"
else
  puts "Sorry, you weren't invited. Please check with the host of the party for more details"
end
```

Comment: What's `count` for? If you need it you can always get it from `friends_list.length`.

Comment: Also, small issue: you'll get prompts like `"1th person's name: "` and `"2th person's name: "` with the code as is. Rails has an [ordinalize](https://apidock.com/rails/Integer/ordinalize) method for this, while [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081926/how-do-i-format-a-date-in-ruby-to-include-rd-as-in-3rd) caters for Ruby. Regardless, +1 for a good answer to the question :)

Comment: Thanks mate, works fine. I liked this answer more because it was easier to understand because I just started a week ago. Cheers

Comment: No, don't do this. It's not necessary to loop and count.

Comment: I tried to keep it simple but you are right. Thanks for good feedback.