# How to generate the 'th' or 'st' output using the daystrftime (DateTime) ruby

Tags: ruby, datetime

How can I generate the `Wednesday 9th, 9:24pm` using the `daystrftime` -> `(DateTime)` method?

I am using the `Time.now.strftime("%A%e, %l:%M%P")` and the output is `Wednesday 9,  9:24pm`
But how can I add the `th` or `nd` suffix?

Ideal output should be `Wednesday 9th, 9:24pm` or `Wednesday 2nd,  9:24pm` or `Wednesday 1st,  9:24pm`

Comment: Readers: some answers posted here before the question was closed as a dup have since been posted at [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081926/how-do-i-format-a-date-in-ruby-to-include-rd-as-in-3rd) for which this question was found to be a dup.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the answer of @steenslag to solve two issues:

- the `%e` pattern is space padded which does lead to incosistent spacing (use `%-d`)
- extend case statement to deal with two digit day of month (21 - 31)

```rb
def format(time)
  time.strftime("%A %-d, %l:%M%P").sub!(/\d?\d/) do |day|
    case day
    when "1", "21", "31" then "#{day}st"
    when "2", "22" then "#{day}nd"
    when "3", "23" then "#{day}rd"
    else "#{day}th"
    end
  end
end


p format(Time.new(2020, 1, 1))
p format(Time.new(2020, 1, 2))
p format(Time.new(2020, 1, 3))
p format(Time.new(2020, 1, 4))
p format(Time.new(2020, 1, 11))
p format(Time.new(2020, 1, 12))
p format(Time.new(2020, 1, 13))
p format(Time.new(2020, 1, 14))
p format(Time.new(2020, 1, 21))
p format(Time.new(2020, 1, 22))
p format(Time.new(2020, 1, 23))
p format(Time.new(2020, 1, 24))
p format(Time.new(2020, 1, 30))
p format(Time.new(2020, 1, 31))
```

Comment: Yes, that is better.

Answer (score 2):

### Map Ordinals in a Hash; Handle 11-13 as a Special Case

There might be a more elegant way to do this, but in general you need to define your own mapping for the ordinal suffix you need. In particular, you need to handle 11-13 specially. As one example, `13th` and `23rd` have different ordinal suffixes, even though they both end in `3`.

For most values, you can look up the correct suffix in the *ordinals* hash below by applying [Integer#modulo(10)](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Integer.html#method-i-modulo) to the day of the month. The modulo operation effectively gives you the last digit when dealing with valid days of the month, and we'll use that digit as a hash key to retrieve the right suffix for [String#sub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-sub).

The following code highlights this approach.

```rb
ordinals = { 
  1 => 'st',
  2 => 'nd',
  3 => 'rd',
  4 => 'th',
  5 => 'th',
  6 => 'th',
  7 => 'th',
  8 => 'th',
  9 => 'th',
  0 => 'th',
}

str        = 'Wednesday 9, 9:24pm'
date_expr  = /\d+(?=,)/
date       = str.match(date_expr).to_s.to_i
ord_suffix = case date
             when 11..13 then 'th'
             else ordinals[date % 10] 
             end 

str.sub date_expr, "#{date}#{ord_suffix}"
#=> "Wednesday 9th, 9:24pm"
```

Comment: A great answer that unfortunately won't be seen by many. I'd encourage you to post this on the not-closed question to give it more visibility.

Comment: Please note that the earlier pure-Ruby solution has been reopened.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in this answer - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165170/in-ruby-on-rails-how-do-i-format-a-date-with-the-th-suffix-as-in-sun-oct-5)
we can use similar approach here:

```
time = Time.new
time.strftime("%A #{time.day.ordinalize},%l:%M%P") -> Wednesday 9th, 4:10pm
```

Comment: I suggest you point out that `require 'active_support/core_ext/integer/inflections'` is needed if Rails is not being used.